# How do I set up a virtual private network in VirtualBox?

Tags: 10.10, server, virtualbox, vpn

I am trying to set up a VPN in a virtual box machine running Ubuntu 10.10. All attempts so far have failed and even when I set up the VPN it keeps saying failed connection. Any help at all here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify what machines are involved? What is the VPN host, and what are its clients? What kind of VPN are you trying to set up, and what have you done to try to do so? Also, how is the VirtualBox client's network adapter attached to the VirtualBox host's network? Feel free to edit your original question at any time when you need to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of vpn are you trying to connect? is it cisco vpn? if its cisco vpn, then try using the cisco client. the tutorial to compile can be found [here](http://projects.tuxx-home.at/?id=cisco_vpn_client) and [here](http://www.lamnk.com/blog/vpn/how-to-install-cisco-vpn-client-on-ubuntu-jaunty-jackalope-and-karmic-koala-64-bit/). The network manager vpnc did not work for me so i took to the compiling.

Also , if you are using virtualbox, set the network adapter settings to NAT .